# Android Loader application resume

Tags: android, listview, loader, resume

I am building an application that scans the sdcard for music files and put it in a listview.
Since it's a big process I put it in a loader and my callback will create a new adapter and set it in my listview.

It seems to be working fine but when I open another application and then come back, it will run the loader again.

Is there anyway to have the loader run only on create but not on resume?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Is there anyway to have the loader run only on create but not on resume?` yes if you put the code only in `onCreate()` then it will only run inside `onCreate()` not `onResume()` however it is also possible that when you open another application the system may reclaim the resources from your app if it needs them in which case when you navigate back to yours it is going to call `onCreate()` again.

Comment: oh so just forget about the loader and spawn a thread to do it?